# Parsing xml in phonegap

Tags: javascript, xml, cordova

I am having a problem displaying xml (RSS) data. And before some of you jump on your high horse - yes I have searched and yes I have found articles, and yes, I thought I was doing it right but obviously making a mistake somewhere. So if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correct it please, that would be most helpful.

I think where I am going wrong is at the var title and var description?

XML:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
<channel>
<generator>NFE/1.0</generator>
<title>Dublin - Google News</title>
<link>http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&amp;ned=uk&amp;hl=en&amp;q=Dublin</link>
<language>en</language>
<webMaster>news-feedback@google.com</webMaster>
<copyright>&amp;copy;2014 Google</copyright>
<pubDate>Thu, 20 Mar 2014 19:50:02 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 20 Mar 2014 19:50:02 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<image>
<title>Dublin - Google News</title>
<url>http://www.gstatic.com/news-static/img/logo/en_uk/news.gif</url>
<link>http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&amp;ned=uk&amp;hl=en&amp;q=Dublin</link>
</image>
<item>
<title>Man fights for life after vicious assault in Dublin city centre - Irish Independent</title>
<link>http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=uk&amp;usg=AFQjCNHPJJxuncjx05f8z70t665o7-SgRw&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=43982351859963&amp;ei=akYrU_jjJeaMiAbnPg&amp;url=http://www.independent.ie/irish-news/man-fights-for-life-after-vicious-assault-in-dublin-city-centre-30110179.html</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">tag:news.google.com,2005:cluster=http://www.independent.ie/irish-news/man-fights-for-life-after-vicious-assault-in-dublin-city-centre-30110179.html</guid>
<pubDate>Thu, 20 Mar 2014 14:59:42 GMT</pubDate>
<description>&lt;table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;">&lt;tr>&lt;td width="80" align="center" valign="top">&lt;font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=uk&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNGDH5i8UFznPc5a49QarwHY_xY4WQ&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=43982351859963&amp;amp;ei=akYrU_jjJeaMiAbnPg&amp;amp;url=http://www.irishtimes.com/news/ireland/irish-news/two-youths-held-over-dublin-st-patrick-s-day-assault-1.1732584">&lt;img src="//t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTayEcmXujn1mjWMu1X45BEzNozKyu1Jb8vhW2QVD2L4hQCoVx4pgwx67wh4kXMDtsYZxeHSzJf" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80" />&lt;br />&lt;font size="-2">Irish Times&lt;/font>&lt;/a>&lt;/font>&lt;/td>&lt;td valign="top" class="j">&lt;font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif">&lt;br />&lt;div style="padding-top:0.8em;">&lt;img alt="" height="1" width="1" />&lt;/div>&lt;div class="lh">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=uk&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNHPJJxuncjx05f8z70t665o7-SgRw&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=43982351859963&amp;amp;ei=akYrU_jjJeaMiAbnPg&amp;amp;url=http://www.independent.ie/irish-news/man-fights-for-life-after-vicious-assault-in-dublin-city-centre-30110179.html">&lt;b>Man fights for life after vicious assault in &lt;b>Dublin&lt;/b> city centre&lt;/b>&lt;/a>&lt;br />&lt;font size="-1">&lt;b>&lt;font color="#6f6f6f">Irish Independent&lt;/font>&lt;/b>&lt;/font>&lt;br />&lt;font size="-1">The man, aged 42-years-old, had been part of a group of four men who had been drinking in an open area of a flat complex on Montague Place in &lt;b>Dublin&amp;#39;s&lt;/b> south inner city when he sustained the injuries. He was rushed to the nearby St James&amp;#39;s Hospital by&amp;nbsp;&lt;b>...&lt;/b>&lt;/font>&lt;br />&lt;font size="-1">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=uk&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNGE6lfnL5NQQneBR0RMm3xB_dBqZA&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=43982351859963&amp;amp;ei=akYrU_jjJeaMiAbnPg&amp;amp;url=http://www.rte.ie/news/2014/0319/603252-investigation-after-serious-assault-in-dublin/">YouTube video shows man being attacked in &lt;b>Dublin&lt;/b>&lt;/a>&lt;font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f">&lt;nobr>RTE.ie&lt;/nobr>&lt;/font>&lt;/font>&lt;br />&lt;font size="-1">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=uk&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNGDH5i8UFznPc5a49QarwHY_xY4WQ&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=43982351859963&amp;amp;ei=akYrU_jjJeaMiAbnPg&amp;amp;url=http://www.irishtimes.com/news/ireland/irish-news/two-youths-held-over-dublin-st-patrick-s-day-assault-1.1732584">Two youths held over &lt;b>Dublin&lt;/b> St Patrick&amp;#39;s Day assault&lt;/a>&lt;font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f">&lt;nobr>Irish Times&lt;/nobr>&lt;/font>&lt;/font>&lt;br />&lt;font size="-1">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=uk&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNFrUNoCf336UNzMbps1g3_7MlZzig&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=43982351859963&amp;amp;ei=akYrU_jjJeaMiAbnPg&amp;amp;url=http://www.kildare-nationalist.ie/2014/03/20/two-teens-arrested-over-st-patricks-day-assault-in-dublin/">Two teens arrested over St Patrick&amp;#39;s Day assault in &lt;b>Dublin&lt;/b>&lt;/a>&lt;font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f">&lt;nobr>Kildare Nationalist&lt;/nobr>&lt;/font>&lt;/font>&lt;br />&lt;font size="-1" class="p">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=uk&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNHGxp9KnIFhk7UY-c1g1CYDeDWhWg&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=43982351859963&amp;amp;ei=akYrU_jjJeaMiAbnPg&amp;amp;url=http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/horrific-video-captures-man-being-3259128">&lt;nobr>Mirror.co.uk&lt;/nobr>&lt;/a>&amp;nbsp;-&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=uk&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNGfnZJesJWCA_RdNs4wMtA7I_C-7g&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=43982351859963&amp;amp;ei=akYrU_jjJeaMiAbnPg&amp;amp;url=http://www.carlow-nationalist.ie/2014/03/20/man-critically-ill-after-dublin-city-centre-assault/">&lt;nobr>The Nationalist&lt;/nobr>&lt;/a>&amp;nbsp;-&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=uk&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNHGOSGKkx_VhRoYNodHlBobNNwZTw&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=43982351859963&amp;amp;ei=akYrU_jjJeaMiAbnPg&amp;amp;url=http://www.breakingnews.ie/ireland/gardai-probe-dublin-assault-after-shocking-video-posted-online-625420.html">&lt;nobr>BreakingNews.ie&lt;/nobr>&lt;/a>&lt;/font>&lt;br />&lt;font class="p" size="-1">&lt;a class="p" href="http://news.google.com/news/more?ncl=dRTJlggdIkP-3hMVAmRC3RBCSq46M&amp;amp;authuser=0&amp;amp;ned=uk">&lt;nobr>&lt;b>all 24 news articles&amp;nbsp;&amp;raquo;&lt;/b>&lt;/nobr>&lt;/a>&lt;/font>&lt;/div>&lt;/font>&lt;/td>&lt;/tr>&lt;/table></description>
</item>
```

Javascript:

```
  function GetData()
{   

    var api = "http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=uk&hl=en&q=Dublin&cf=all&output=rss";

    alert('called ' + api);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: api,
            dataType: "xml",
            cache: false,
            success: function(xml) {


                var title = $(xml).find('item["item"]').text()
                var description = $(xml).find('item["description"]').text()



                $('#headername').html('<h3>' + title + '</h3><br /><p>' + name + '</p>');

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#spinner').hide();
            });


            },
            error: function() {

                alert('Cannot find parse data')

            }
        }); 

}
    window.onload = GetData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using attribute selectors when the tags have no attributes that match.  Just use straight finds.

```
            var title = $(xml).find('item').text()
            var description = $(xml).find('description').text()
```

Keep in mind that `find` finds ALL matching tags, so you may want to add `:first` to the selector or iterate via each.

Also, I suggest mapping the results of `$(xml)` to a variable so that you don't force it to parse the same XML string over and over.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Great to get some proper advice here for a change.